# Simple Linux/X11 programme to grab and keep the keyboard focus?

Tags: python, linux, keyboard, x11

I am writing a simple typing break / anti-RSI programme on Linux (Ubuntu) in Python. I asked similar questions about locking the keyboard ( [How do I 'lock the keyboard' to prevent any more keypresses being sent on X11/Linux/Gnome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10740067/how-do-i-lock-the-keyboard-to-prevent-any-more-keypresses-being-sent-on-x11-li) and [Releasing all keys after disabling the keyboard in X11/Linux using xinput?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758473/releasing-all-keys-after-disabling-the-keyboard-in-x11-linux-using-xinput) ) and someone suggested ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/10769704/161922 ) that grabbing the keyboard focus would be the best way. However I'm new to X11 programming. How would I do that in Python? (Presume I have python-xlib or whatever installed, I can also install anything from pypi or apt).

How do you make a simple X11 application that will grab the keyboard focus (even if another window is currently focussed). It should not be possible for the user to alt-tab or alt-f4 away from this (i.e. there is no escape). However it should be possible to 'release' this 'grabbing' later or at any time.

Comment: Try looking at how a screensaver does it maybe?

Answer (score 0):

So it's been a literal decade but by some spectacular coincidence I stumbled upon this right after writing such a program so it felt silly to not mention it in case it may be useful to any one else who comes across this: [https://git.sr.ht/~kitt/inputgrabby](https://git.sr.ht/%7Ekitt/inputgrabby).

The main idea to grabbing the keyboard is to just to call either [`XGrabKeyboard`](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/XGrabKeyboard.html) if using Xlib or as my program uses xcb, `xcb_grab_keyboard`. For the grab to succeed, the grab_window must be mapped (i.e. visible); using the root window works fine if you do not wish to map a new window.