# What python module would let me lock my keyboard for a certain period of time?

Tags: python

I want to write a python code to lock my keyboard for a certain amount of time. Pythoncom module didn't work or may not exist.

Comment: We're not a code-writing website. What have you already tried?

Comment: it has been already asked here ( for Linux ):
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10740067/how-do-i-lock-the-keyboard-to-prevent-any-more-keypresses-being-sent-on-x11-li

Answer (score 0):

It'll be OS-specific. On Windows you may use [`BlockInput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646290(v=vs.85).aspx) function available from Windows API.

```
import ctypes
ctypes.cdll.user32.BlockInput(True)
```

Comment: Please ***do NOT*** answer off-topic questions, *especially* gimme-teh-codez questions like this.

Comment: @cybermonkey You may find [a meta-discussion on the matter interesting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288133/is-using-stack-overflow-for-gimme-codez-questions-encouraged). I strongly agree with your sentiment, but have concluded that it is a Sisyphean task unless the incentives change and there's no sign of that.